# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed due to:

Tags: android, android-studio

While trying to launch my app in Android Studio I am getting this error.
I already tried to clean the project and build it again.
I also did a cold boot of the emulators.
Thank you for your help!!!

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/--/AndroidStudioProjects/acude/app/build/intermediates/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -Xlint:deprecation -S 3696631' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install-create':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown option -X
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.makeInstallParams(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2883)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1412)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:195)
at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21623)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4603)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4302)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)''
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

Comment: Just to rule out anything specific with the app you are working with, can you run a brand new blank app in the emulator? Also, make sure your run destination is properly selected and that your emulator will run on its own..

Comment: @JerseyDevel I have test a new blank app and it work correctly. I also have checked that the run destination its the correct so the emulator is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a big investigation I found the error.
The command -**Xlint** cannot be launch from java.

To change the install command you must go to **run** > **edit configurations** and delete the comments in Install Flags

Answer (score 2):

Simply go to **Run** -> **Edit Configurations**

Mark check on the followings:

- Install for all users (if already installed, will only update for existing users)
- Always install with package manager (disables deploy optimizations on Android 11 and later)

Answer (score 1):

I am using at this time: Android Studio Koala | 2023.3.2 Canary 2

Simply go to Run -> Edit Configurations -> Installation Option -> Deploy: Select 'APK from app bundle' option

Mark check on the followings:

Install for all users (if already installed, will only update for existing users)
Always install with package manager (disables deploy optimizations on Android 11 and later)